# How to use namespaced models with polymorphic_path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails is usually very clever at determining the correct routes when provided with objects. For example

```
<%= form_for [@parent,@child] do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= polymorphic_path(@parent,@child) %>
```

But I always run into problems when using namespaced models.

For example, when using:

```
@parent = ActsAs::Draft.find(params[:draft_id])
@child = ActsAs::Vote.new
```

Rails attempts to use

```
polymorphic_path(@parent,@child) = acts_as/drafts/:id/acts_as/votes
```

which makes sense. But how to define this route?

using

```
namespace :acts_as do 
  resources :drafts do 
    namespace :acts_as do
      resources :votes 
    end
  end
end
```

Rails attempts to find a double namespaced controller

```
ActsAs::ActsAs::Votes
```

setting module to nil

```
namespace :acts_as do 
  resources :drafts do 
    namespace :acts_as, module: nil do
      resources :votes 
    end
  end
end
```

raises a `wrong constant name` error, I assume because Rails is now looking for `Votes` rather than `ActsAs::Votes`.

explicitly defining teh controller

```
resources :votes, controller: "acts_as/votes"
```

does not help.

I must be overlooking something obvious here!

What is the correct way to use namespaced models with `polymorphic_path`?

Comment: The title of the question is a bit misleading to say the least.

Comment: @Iceman sorry, not sure what happened there. the title from a previous/ unrelated post was set.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I upvoted since I've wrestled with a similar problem myself. Would be interesting to see a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Iceman, what solutions have you tried? And which are you still using?

Comment: It was on an old project so I don't have the code anymore. Essentially I just gave up and did not use namespaces. I know it doesn't help you very much, but that is basically what happened.